# CSS Grid - Two column layout with independent scrollable areas

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to achieve a layout, which has two columns fitting the height of the screen.

- The left column has two rows, each of the row takes 50% of the visible available height (no fixed height, it should be responsive). If the content of each row would be greater than 50%, it should be scrollable.
- The right column takes the full height. If its content spans over the visible screen a scrollbar should be displayed.

The current behaviour of my [prototype](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-rxvply?file=index.html) is the following. The right side is working. However I need some help for the left side, because the first row takes more space than the second row:
[image]

The desired layout should look like the following:
[image]

Comment: So is the problem that there is some stuff which is shown before the columns and therefore the column height can’t be the full 100vh? Otherwise your three scrollable areas are working OK, ie are individually scrollable.

Comment: Yes, indeed! Some stuff is shown before the columns.  I've edited my example with two screenshots, which clarifies this hopefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the container to be the height of the screen you can set `.left` and `.right` to `height: 100vh;`

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-zskodr?file=styles.css)

### EDIT

You could do use a flexbox to contain the left side, and make that center and contain the elements. I have reduced the `min-height` to `100px` to make the demo work in the preview better, but it is easily changeable to another size.

```css
.ctnr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(0, 1fr) auto;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" 
                         "nav main" 
                       "footer footer";
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: turquoise;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.scroll-left {
  overflow: scroll;
  flex: 1;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: orange;
  overflow: scroll;
  min-height: 100px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctnr">
  <header>
    <h3>header</h3>
    <div>some content</div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <div class="scroll-left">
      nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>nav<br>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-left">
      nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>nav2<br>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main>main main main main
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>    main main mainmain
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>    main main main
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach would work if there is no other content on the site. However I've got some heading or paragraph etc. which also takes height outside of my grid container. Now the first row takes `50vh` and the second row is pushed outside of the window.

I've adjusted my [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-rxvply?file=index.html)

Comment: So should the content make the grid smaller, or should it push it down, what if the content fits the entire screen, should the grid have a min height?

Comment: The content should shrink the grid until a minimum height has been reached.  The left grid rows should shrink equally since this minimal height is reaced. (eg 200px each). If there is more space available they should fit the available height.